# How to access MultiValueField's SubFields in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I am trying to get a nice presentatin of a DatTime picker following [this approach](http://copiesofcopies.org/webl/2010/04/26/a-better-datetime-widget-for-django/).
So I have a subclass of MultiValueField with two SubFields and a widget which is a subclass of MultiWidget and which passes the correct css classes to its subwidgets in order to get JQueryUI to mark one of the inputs as a date picker.
Now I want to access the resulting SubFields of the MultiValueField seperately in my templates, rendering them in different places in a table.
But I cannot see a way to address them.
Which object do I have to refer to in the template?
Depending on what I use in my template I can access most of the object, but none of them render into HTML. All I can get is the default str() output for the objects.

For example,  `form.date_time.field.time_field.widget` "renders" into `<django.forms.widgets.TimeInput object at 0x7fe018033f90>`

Accessing the fields in question instead gives similar results.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Looking for the same solution. @gorus were you able to overcome this?

Comment: This solution worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866936/render-only-one-part-of-a-multiwidget-in-django